# Script MS Word 2010 to open HTM Files and Save As DOCX files

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a bunch of .htm files and I want them to be .docx files. How can I script Word to open them all and save-as them as .docx files?

I'm ok with manually initiating the process. I don't need something that will wait around for more files, just something that will run on demand and process a whole folder of files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub ConvertHTMtoDOCX()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .Show
        strPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) + "\"
    End With

    strFilename = Dir(strPath & "*.htm")

    While Len(strFilename) <> 0
        Set myDoc = Documents.Open(strPath & strFilename)
        strNewName = strPath & strFilename & ".docx"
        myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strNewName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
        myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        strFilename = Dir()
    Wend

End Sub
```

<sup>Tested with 2 .HTM files on my desktop, Windows 7 x64 and Office 2013</sup>

Comment: This seems like it should work, it seems pretty straight forward, but it's complaining about the line:    myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strNewName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault

Comment: Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: For me it's working. You have to debug it. When the error occurs, hover the mouse over `strPath`, `strFilename` and `strNewName` and look what values are in it. You can also right-click them and "Add watch" to view them. Also, open the immidiate window and type `?wdFormatDocumentDefault` and press enter to view the underlying integer value of that constant

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that one of the files was named .htm with no actual name. Once I renamed it, the macro was able to start processing all the files in the folder.